# Identificated a drop activity

Tags: c#, wpf, workflow-foundation-4

I'm working in a WPF. I have the following problem. When I dropped a new activity to the designer, I need to store some information in an hashtable. This hashtable must be the following structure:

Key: ACTIVITY OBJECT DROPPED   VALUE: List of variables that this activity creates at runtime.

Now, I have the following code in the Window class:

```
 private void AddDesigner()
 {
     this.wd = new WorkflowDesigner();
     ------------------------
     ModelService ms = wd.Context.Services.GetService<ModelService>();
     if (ms != null)
            ms.ModelChanged += new EventHandler<ModelChangedEventArgs>(ms_ModelChanged);
 }
```

and ms_ModelChanged:

```
 void ms_ModelChanged(object sender, ModelChangedEventArgs e)
 {
        if (e.ItemsAdded != null)
        {
            ModelItem item = e.ItemsAdded.FirstOrDefault<ModelItem>();
            var test = item.GetCurrentValue() as CountActivity;
            RulesDll.ObjectsClass.HashTableActivity.HashActivity.Add(XXXX, lista);
        }

        else if (e.ItemsRemoved != null)
        {
            ModelItem item = e.ItemsRemoved.FirstOrDefault<ModelItem>();
            //mi.Properties["Variables"].Collection.Remove(n);
        }
    }
```

In: RulesDll.ObjectsClass.HashTableActivity.HashActivity.Add(XXXX, lista);

Where XXXX must be the Object item dropped in the designer.... OK, As I know it's impossible to add a duplicate key in an hashtable, si when I drop two same activities in the designer with the following code:

RulesDll.ObjectsClass.HashTableActivity.HashActivity.Add(item, lista);

An error saying NOT DUPLICATED value is permitted in hashtable as normal....

So what I have to do to identificated the activity that I drop in the designer?

Comment: I don't known what you are trying to do but it doesn't sound good! :)

Comment: This does not sound like a good design.  Have you consider using a workflow extension for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use current activity object as key?

```
hashtable.Add(item.GetCurrentValue(), ...);
```

Anyway, almost certaintly Hashtable is using `System.Object.GetHashCode()` internally which "[does not guarantee unique return values for different objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode)" although a clash is hard to happen.

At workflow design time you don't have access to some kind of *activity unique id*. You're on your own. Like I said, I don't known what you are trying to do but it doesn't sound good!

Comment: Thanks for all answers! I can't use item.GetCurrentValue() becouse if I drop two same activities in the designer, a duplicate error key is displaying in the debug... So I don't know what I have to do to identificated every activity that I drop it...